# how to calculate memory consummation for my application in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

In application,displaying the high resolution images and have some memory leaks so i would like to calculate the memory consumption of each statement to find out the leaks.

is there any method to calculate the memory (MB or KB)?

I need Like this:

// this is my method

```
 + (unsigned char *) convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:(UIImage *) image {

//Run a method to caclate the memory(MB or KB)  --- Before
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

// Create a bitmap context to draw the uiimage into
CGContextRef context = [self newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:imageRef];

if(!context) {
    return NULL;
}

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

// Draw image into the context to get the raw image data
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);

// Get a pointer to the data    
unsigned char *bitmapData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

// Copy the data and release the memory (return memory allocated with new)
size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

unsigned char *newBitmap = NULL;

if(bitmapData) {
    newBitmap = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * bytesPerRow * height);

    if(newBitmap) { // Copy the data
        for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
            newBitmap[i] = bitmapData[i];
        }
    }

    free(bitmapData);

} else {
    NSLog(@"Error getting bitmap pixel data\n");
}

CGContextRelease(context);
//Run a method to calculate the memory(MB or KB)    --- After
return newBitmap;
```

}

Comment: Goto -> Product -> Profile -> Allocations

Comment: @ Prince Thanks. I need to calculate memory statement by statement.